# Using alias for changing the default python version

Tags: python, bash, terminal

I would like to know if using `alias` in terminal to change the default python version has positive effects on subsequent calls of python in scripts?

For example, I use

```
$ alias python=python36
$ ./run_program
```

Now assume run_program is a script that call multiple nested scripts and inside them, the command is `python foo.py`. Will they execute `python36` or `python2`?

Or that `alias` affects only direct python commands in current shell?

Comment: aliases are not available in subshells, better to use functions

Comment: So, what is the system wide solution then?

Comment: probably just search for python, `whereis python`. And replace that with whatever `whereis python3` returns. This is a **really bad** idea btw, but it should do the trick. Something like `mv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`, I would be surprised if the system is not trashed after this. You should probably consider to use a virtual environment instead of messing with system's python installations.

Comment: @mahmood: If you want systemwide override of `python2` to `python36` then use: `python() { python36 "$@"; }; export -f python`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alias` are not exported to sub-shells. It is better to use functions for this purpose. If you want systemwide override of python2 to python36 then use this code in your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
python() { python36 "$@"; }

export -f python
```

Then check python version in any script by using:

```
python -V
```

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT DO THIS IN YOUR SYSTEM**

Just tried that out of curiosity. And it does work, not sure what broke if anything.

```bash
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
$ sudo cp /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.bak
$ sudo cp /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
$ python -V
Python 3.7.4
```

And, since I have no interest in finding what broke:

```bash
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/python.bak /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I don't have root access. Probably virtual env is the best bet. I thought there might be a better idea.

Comment: Yes, this totally wicked. Don't do it. But since one can do whatever it wishes in Linux, you can do it. But don't do it.

Comment: Virtual environments *are* the better idea.

Comment: @chepner For sure. Not even discuss able.