# Why vscode terminal show python version difference with interpreter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

as you see "python --version show python3.10.4

but the interpreter show python 3.7.3

[image]

how can i change the envirnment in vscode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the Python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: related (duplicates?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/60836646/11107541 https://stackoverflow.com/q/66670568/11107541

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the interpreter version being used by VSCode, you should be able to select different versions across your device.

[image: Interpreter version]

Comment: i have been try this before , still can not change envirroment to python 3.7 . 

because i want to run streamlit in vscode .

Comment: Anaconda Navigator open terminal can succeed to change the environments in terminal , but vscode can not .

Comment: @KKC Perhaps you could try to run it in a virtual environment.

Comment: @KKC Also since the interpreter version seems to be the desired one (3.7), you could just create an alias in your terminal to address the interpreter version, unless you want to run it on 3.10.

Comment: thanks a lot , how can it creata alias in your terminal to address the interpreter version,

Comment: @KKC Apparently aliases don't work in subshells, so you need to use functions. This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58417030/18468350

Comment: But you can always revert to virtual envs which helps you to select isolated versions for each project.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the interpreter in VSCode:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters

To run `streamlit` in `vscode`:
Open the `launch.json` file of your project.
Copy the following:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        

        {
            "name": "Python:Streamlit",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "streamlit",
            
            "args": [
                
                "run",
                "${file}"
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to your setting.json (crtl+shift+P "preferences: open settings(JSON)").

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PATH": ""
}
```